# Function and Consumer restrictions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I decided to use functions in my method as parameter and found rather unpleasant things. Here is an example:

```
final Random random = new Random();

public interface Animal {
    public void sleep();
}

public class Cat implements Animal {

    public boolean isAffectionate() {
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }

    public void meow() {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }

    @Override
    public void sleep() {
        System.out.println("my sofa");
    }
}

public class Dog implements Animal {

    public boolean isAngry() {
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("woof-woof");
    }

    @Override
    public void sleep() {
        System.out.println("my carpet");
    }
}

public boolean isOwnerAtHome() {
    return random.nextBoolean();
}

public <T, A extends Animal> T anyAction(Class<A> clazz, Function<A, T> action)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    A animal;
    animal = (A) clazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
    T t;
    if (isOwnerAtHome()) {
        t = action.apply(animal);
    } else {
        animal.sleep();
        t = action.apply(animal);
    }
    return t;
}
```

I know that this code is awful but the question is not about code design. Let's say I want to continue to use lambdas and design similar to it.

To see cat activity (but only if it produces something - not `void`):

```
public boolean booleanCatActionToday()
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    return anyAction(Cat.class, c -> c.isAffectionate());
}
```

To see `void` activity I have to use this work around:

```
public <A extends Animal> void voidAction(Class<A> clazz, Consumer<A> action)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Function<A, Boolean> function = animal -> {
        action.accept(animal);
        return true;
    };
    anyAction(clazz, function);
}
```

and only then:

```
public void voidCatActionToday()
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    voidAction(Cat.class, c -> c.meow());
}
```

Quite messy. Even methods (`anyAction` and `voidAction`) should have different names.

Is it possible to make it less messy using lambdas and without full rewrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you think it’s complicated, because you make it complicated:

```
public <T, A extends Animal> T anyAction(Supplier<A> s, Function<A, T> action) {
    A animal=s.get();
    if (!isOwnerAtHome()) animal.sleep();
    return action.apply(animal);
}
public <A extends Animal> void anyAction(Supplier<A> s, Consumer<A> action) {
    anyAction(s, a -> { action.accept(a); return null; }); 
}
public boolean booleanCatActionToday() {
    return anyAction(Cat::new, Cat::isAffectionate);
}
public void voidCatActionToday() {
    anyAction(Cat::new, Cat::meow);
}
```

Yes, there is a translation step needed to support `Consumer` as `Function`, but it’s a single line of code that has to be implemented only once…

For certain lambda expression, it might be helpful to have the two `anyAction` methods differently named to help the compiler to disambiguate, but that does not affect the naming scheme of the *callers*, i.e. `booleanCatActionToday` and `voidCatActionToday`. I don’t know why you named these methods that way and what the actual intended use is, so it’s hard to suggest more useful names for them.

---

As a more general solution you can have a single utility method in your code base like

```
public static <T> Function<T,Void> noResult(Consumer<T> c) {
    return t -> { c.accept(t); return null; };
}
```

which you can `static import` and you will never need an overloaded method as you can call the method accepting a `Function` as simple as

```
public void voidCatActionToday() {
    anyAction(Cat::new, noResult(Cat::meow));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually we use some semantics to distinguish between functions that return a result and functions that don't e.g.:

```
static void <A extends Animal> void action(
    Class<A> type,
    Consumer<? super A> theAction) {...}

static void <A extends Animal, T> query(
    Class<A> type,
    Function<? super A, ? extends T> theQuery) {...}

Animal.action(Cat.class, Cat::meow);
boolean result =
    Animal.query(Cat.class, Cat::isAffectionate);
```

This is because they usually mean different things so there's no reason to conflate them.

If you need to reuse something then yes you need to do something kludgy:

```
Animal.query(type, a -> {
    theAction.accept(a);
    return null;
});
```

Or possibly consider factoring it a different way:

```
private static <A extends Animal> Optional<A> create(
        Class<A> type) throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    A a = type.getConstructor().newInstance();

    if (!a.isOwnerHome()) {
        a.sleep();
    }

    return a;
}

// "action"
theAction.accept(create(type));
// "query"
return theQuery.apply(create(type));
```

Generally speaking, keep in mind that the internals of an API might not be pretty or perfect and the goal is instead that it's nice to use from the *outside*.

Suppose that lambdas were designed in such a way that a `Consumer<T>` was somehow implicitly convertible to a `Function<T, Void>`. This would be convenient for API designers who want to reuse a bit of code, but it would open a pathway for users of those APIs to use them in a nonsensical/incorrect way:

```
<T> void send(List<T> elements) {
    elements.stream()
        // using 'map' to log
        // when 'peek' is designed for this purpose
        .map(e -> Debug.log("sending " + e))
        .forEach(this::send);
}
```